# Calculating point and dimensions of maximum rotated rectangle inside rectangle

Tags: objective-c, math

I have a rectangle that has to be rotated always the same amount of degrees. Lets call this angle alpha ().

The width (w) and height (h) of this rectangle can vary. The rectangle has always to fit rotated inside the big rectangle. It must be scaled up or down to fit inside the gray rectangle.

NOTE: Alpha is the angle between w and the horizontal line.

So, there are 3 kinds of rectangles where

```
w > h
w < h  or
w = h
```

See the picture below.

[image]

What I know:

1. The big rectangle has width of R and height of K and I know both values;
2. w and h are unknown;
3. the rectangle is always rotated  degrees;
4. I know the value of w/h. I call this "ratioWH";
5. red rectangle is always centered horizontally and vertically on the gray rectangle

what I need to know:

1. the maximum values of w and h that will fit the gray rectangle for each case of w and h.
2. the coordinates of point **P**, assuming that 0,0 is at the upper left of the gray rectangle.

This is what I did so far, but this is not giving the correct values:

```
CGPoint P = CGPointZero;

if (ratioWH > 0) { // means w > h

    maxH = R / (ratioWH * fabsf(cosf(theta)) + fabsf(sinf(theta)));
    maxW = maxH * ratioWH;

    // P.x = 0.0f;  // P.x is already zero
    CGFloat marginY = (K - maxW * fabsf(sinf(theta)) - maxH * fabsf(cosf(theta))) / 2.0f;
    P.y = marginY +  maxW * fabsf(sinf(theta));

} else { // w <= h

    maxW  = K / (fabsf(cosf(theta) / ratioImagemXY) + fabsf(sinf(theta)));
    maxH = maxW / ratioWH;


    P.x = (R - maxW * fabsf(cosf(theta)) - maxH * fabsf(sinf(theta))) / 2.0f;
    P.y = maxW * fabsf(sinf(theta));

}
```

any clues? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *the maximum values of w and h that will fit the gray rectangle for each case of w and h* ?  Which is angle alpha in your drawing ?

Comment: What I mean is this: the red rectangle must fit inside the gray rectangle. I have changed that phrase. Alpha is the angle between w and the horizontal line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I see it is like this...  You work out the total width and total height of the rectangle.  For that, you simply walk along two edges.  Like this:

```
dx = w * cos(theta) + h * sin(theta)
dy = h * cos(theta) + w * sin(theta)
```

These could be negative, so special handling would apply if the rectangle is rotated into other quadrants.  This will happen later.

You now just need the ratio between the width and height.  This is where you decide whether to scale by the vertical amount or the horizontal amount.  It's nothing to do with `w` and `h` -- it's actually about where the rectangle ends up as a result of rotation.  That's what `dx` and `dy` are for.

```
rectratio = abs( dx / dy )
viewratio = R / K
```

If `rectratio` comes out larger than `viewratio` that means the rotated rectangle's horizontal footprint needs to be scaled.  Otherwise you scale by the vertical footprint.

```
if rectratio > viewratio
    scale = R / abs(dx)
else
    scale = K / abs(dy)
end
```

And the scale itself is applied to the original width and height

```
sw = scale * w
sh = scale * h
```

So now you can compute the corners of your rectangle.  It doesn't matter where you start.

```
x[0] = 0
x[1] = x[0] + sw * cos(theta)
x[2] = x[1] + sh * sin(theta)
x[3] = x[2] - sw * cos(theta)

y[0] = 0
y[1] = y[0] - sw * sin(theta)
y[2] = y[1] + sh * cos(theta)
y[3] = y[2] + sw * sin(theta)
```

I've assumed image co-ordinates given that (0,0) is top-left, so increasing `y` moves down.  So, if I haven't made a mistake in my math, the above gives you the rectangle vertices (in clockwise order).

The last thing to do is normalise them...  This means finding the min value of `px` and `py`.  Call them `pxmin` and `pymin`.  I don't need to show code for that.  The idea is to calculate an offset for your rectangle such that the view area is defined by the rectangle `(0,0)` to `(R,K)`.

First we need to find the left and right value of the subview that completely contains our rotated rectangle...  Remember the ratio before:

```
if( rectratio > viewratio )
    // view is too tall, so centre vertically:
    left = 0
    top = (K - scale * abs(dy)) / 2.0
else
    // view is too wide, so centre horizontally:
    left = (R - scale * abs(dx)) / 2.0
    top = 0
end
```

`left` and `top` are now the 'minimum' co-ordinate of our subview that exactly contains the rectangle (floating point rounding errors exempted).  So:

```
left += pxmin
top += pymin
```

Now they are the offset required to shift the rectangle to where it's wanted.  All you do is add `left` and `top` to all your rectangle co-ordinates, and you are done.  The position of `P` is `px[0]` and `py[0]`.  If you rotated by 90 degrees or more, it won't be the top-left vertex.

Comment: Maths is the winner on the day =)  If I were you I'd write a simple test program to verify this.  Animate a rectangle rotating through 360 degrees.  Show the view rectangle and show `P`.  Try for a few different values of `w` and `h`.

Comment: By the way... just a note about rounding error.  Notice how I computed the vertices in clockwise order.  That means your last vertex is going to be affected by the most error.  It might not be at all significant for your application, but in general you may want to compute the last vertex by moving anti-clockwise from the start position, and then for the most distant vertex you can average the values for arriving at that vertex by one of the two possible paths.  You may also need to clamp your vertices to ensure they are actually inside the view rectangle.  Fixing rounding error is a pain.